# Mongo group by time interval and offset interval

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation

I want to query the data based on time, so i tried group by time(15mins) with match followed by group query.
Group by time: 15 mins

```
{$group: {_id: {
        "date": {
            "$subtract": [
                {
                    "$toLong": {
                        "$toDate": "$timeStamp"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$mod": [
                        {
                            "$toLong": {
                                "$toDate": "$timeStamp"
                            }
                        },
                        900000
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },value: {$avg: {
            "$divide": [
                "$rvalue",
                1000
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

This gives me timeStamp with millisec and avg value.
But now i want a query where group by time and offset..query simily to influx group by time(time_intervel,offset_interval)
example influx query:

```
SELECT MEAN("water_level") 
FROM "h2o_feet" 
WHERE "location"='coyote_creek' 
  AND time >= '2015-08-18T00:06:00Z' AND time <= '2015-08-18T00:54:00Z' 
GROUP BY time(18m,6m)
```

I'm expecting a query similar to influx group by time_interval and offset_interval

Comment: Please provide some sample input data.

Comment: You can group by `{ _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$timeStamp", unit: "minute", binSize: 15 } } }`